# Class not registered C++ Builder

Tags: windows-7, c++, delphi

Got installed new **IDE** for C++ development named [C++ builder community](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder/starter) and see what I got:

```
class not registered AssemblyName: Borland.Build.Tasks.Common.dll ClassID: {9351FD3F-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX}
```

I am using **windows 7**. Whenever I execute its **shortcut**, it give error and close.
[image]

Comment: Reinstall the application the installation isn’t complete.  Why is this tagged as Delphi?

Comment: I reinstalled it many times. I get same error on both Delphi IDE & C++ Builder.

Comment: Open an administrator command prompt, go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\<enter your version here>\bin` and enter `regsvr32 "Borland.Build.Tasks.Common.DLL"` what happens now?

Comment: @Mokubai this happens https://ibb.co/KmJs7vC

Comment: Does the file exist on your system?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes : `C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin\Borland.Build.Tasks.Common.dll`

Comment: Which .NET framework is installed? It seems like it [needs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Installation_Notes) at least version 4.5. Which Windows 7 service pack?

Comment: @harrymc I have latest 4.8 .net framework. Win7 service pack SP1

Comment: Have you installed the [Convenience rollup update for Windows 7 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3125574/convenience-rollup-update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2)? See also [this link](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/05/windows-7-now-has-a-service-pack-2-but-dont-call-it-that/).

Comment: @harrymc  I followed and restated but without luck. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-update/how-to-obtain-and-install-windows-7-sp2/c2c7009f-3a10-4199-9c89-48e1e883051e

Comment: @harrymc OMG https://i.ibb.co/ZM37vQX/Capture.png

Comment: You seem to have a mixture of versions. Do you have installed "Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1" in *Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off*?

Comment: @harrymc yes it already checked.

Comment: As I have an Embarcadero account, I downloaded C++ builder community and installed it on a Windows 7 VM. It installed fine, but then doesn't accept my license. This might not be the same as your problem, but it seems that it's not working well on Windows 7. As your problem is different, you might have a conflict with another installed product.

Comment: Yes I also thinks problem is may in win7updates. I installed it in win8.1 in VM and it worked fine.

Comment: But I have done alot work in win7 so I don't want to leave it. Please try solution in the borders of win7.

Comment: I also asked embarcadero company but no response from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have an Embarcadero account, I downloaded *C++ builder community*
and installed it on a Windows 7 VM.
It installed fine, but then doesn't accept my license.
I have verified using its License Manager that my license is well installed,
but I still cannot pass the registration dialog in order to test your problem.

My conclusion is that this product does not function well on Windows 7.
The problem might relate to Microsoft .NET Framework, as your problem
is with an .Net assembly that cannot be loaded, perhaps because of some
missing assembly of Windows.
As you report that the problem was resolved by upgrading to Windows 8,
this further verifies my conclusion.

My real advice is to upgrade to Windows 10 and not stay with outdated and unsafe
Windows versions. Beside bringing many new features and performance enhancements,
Windows 10 receives regular security updates, unlike previous versions.

Comment: I didn't upgraded to win8.1, I used it under win8.1 VM. I know it would solve my problem but it doesn't solve a win7 user problem. Anyway I award +50 bounty for easy ideology. But question still needs to be solved. It is very hard for me to upgrade to upper version as I already done many settings inside win7.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty, and here is some more info. You could try to find the missing/bad assembly by looking into the dependencies of `Borland.Build.Tasks.Common.DLL`. Some products are recommended in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922943/modern-equivalent-of-visual-studio-6-depends-utility). [This](https://www.workshell.co.uk/products/netdepends/) commercial product with trial might be useful.

Comment: `Win7 ! you was my first love, but your owner doesn't want me to use you.` I have been struggling with platform errors for a year. Now I upgraded to win8.1. This was hardest decision ever. Thanks @harrymc

Comment: Windows 10 will be your next love, hopefully.